# Does anyone know why my paper won't stay on the grid? Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Does anyone know why my paper won't stay on the grid?

```
<Grid container>
  <Grid item sm={6} >
    <Paper  elevation={3} className="Paper">
      <Tables ></Tables>
    </Paper>  
  </Grid>
</Grid>

.Paper {

    display: flex;

    justify-content: center;

    align-items: center;

    margin: 1em;

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it would have stayed inside the grid there might be some CSS that is doing that.

However, I would recommend you to use

```
<TableContainer component={Paper}></TableContainer>
```

For using table sitting on Paper.